# URL not connecting to my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Setting up a new spring boot application and it always feels like I have to hold my mouth right to get it to work the first time.

My angular app is doing a post and I know that it's hitting my controller because when I did a get, I got an error saying get wasn't allowed for /login.

Here's my method in my controller that I'm trying to call from my Angular app.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String login(@RequestParam(NetworkKeyNames.KEY_PAYLOAD) String payload) throws IOException {
    log.error("Payload=" + payload);
    TypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {};
    Map<String, String> payloadMap = objectMapper.readValue(payload, typeRef);
    String username = payloadMap.get(NetworkKeyNames.KEY_USERNAME);
    String password = payloadMap.get(NetworkKeyNames.KEY_PASSWORD);

    String result = securityService.login(username, password);
    return result;
}
```

When I hit it, here's the debug information in the console:

```
2018-01-18 14:33:24.865 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: Request(OPTIONS //localhost:8093/login)@6bc51cc8
2018-01-18 14:33:24.866 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing OPTIONS request for [/login]
2018-01-18 14:33:24.866 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /login
2018-01-18 14:33:24.869 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/login]
2018-01-18 14:33:24.869 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2018-01-18 14:33:24.869 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String pizzainthecloud.pizzaplace.controller.PizzaPlaceController.login(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException]
2018-01-18 14:33:24.869 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'pizzaPlaceController'
2018-01-18 14:33:24.870 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2018-01-18 14:33:24.871 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-01-18 14:33:24.871 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2018-01-18 14:33:24.871 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2018-01-18 14:33:24.871 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-01-18 14:33:24.872 DEBUG 27096 --- [qtp779343339-17] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: Request(OPTIONS //localhost:8093/login)@6bc51cc8
```

So it looks as if it's mapping to my method, but the log in the first line never gets called and my breakpoint never gets hit.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste some information about the request from Angular app - what does it look like? What request information can be found in developer tools of your web browser?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Thanks, added information about the call from Angular.

Comment: So you're sending a POST parameter whose value is a JSON object? Why? Why don't you send the JSON as the request body? And let Spring unmarshal the JSON for you? The method should thus be `login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials)`.

Comment: @JBNizet It gives me emotional security. I like to handle my own formatting errors.

Comment: Even if you parse the JSON yourself, at least send it as the request body. Not as a request parameter. This is really clumsy? You wouldn't send XML as an attribute of a JSON object as a request parameter, would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client calling your REST service has CORS enabled, and as such it is sending an initial OPTIONS call, not a POST call as your controller is configured for, as you can see in the first line of your posted log statement.

> (OPTIONS //localhost:8093/login)@6bc51cc8

You will need to either disabled CORS, or add CORS support to your REST API, or put Apache in front of your application to forward requests for the UI and the service being called from the same origin (domain name) so the CORS check request is not triggered.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that, I'd missed the meaning of OPTIONS. Do you know a way that I can allow CrossOrigin for my whole app in my testing profile and then turn it back on my production server?

Comment: As I mentioned if you run all your requests through Apache using the same doamin (same origin)  and have it forward the URI's for your REST service to your SpringBoot service instance you will by pass the need for CORS.   I would do this for local, DEV, STG, and PRD setups.   Otherwise you can add CORS support to your service (I wouldn't) or disabled CORS checking in your JS client.